# Scala - How to convert a Dataset[Row] to a column that can be added to a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset

I'm trying to add a dataframe of one column to a larger dataframe however the issue with the first dataframe is that after creating it and trying to add it to the main dataframe via the command:

```
  df.withColumn("name", dataframe)
```

I get the error:

```
 **found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column**
```

I understand that a Dataset[Row] is supposed to be synonymous with a Dataframe however I'm not sure how to get around this error.

For context, a (really) watered down version of my code is below:

```
// test function - will be used as part of the main script below
def Test(inputone: Double, inputtwo: Double): Double = { 
 var test = (2 * inputone) + inputtwo
 test 
}
```

For the main script (i.e. where the problem lies)

```
//Importing the data via CSV
var df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header",     "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load("/root/file.csv")
```

To give a context of what the data looks like:

```
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, blue: int ... 8 more fields]

+---+----+------+-----+------+------+----+---+-----+-----+
| ID|blue|purple|green|yellow|orange|pink|red|white|black|
+---+----+------+-----+------+------+----+---+-----+-----+
|  1| 500|    44|    0|     0|     3|   0|  5|   43|    2|
|  2| 560|    33|    1|     0|     4|   0| 22|   33|    4|
|  3| 744|    44|    1|    99|     3|1000| 78|   90|    0|
+---+----+------+-----+------+------+----+---+-----+-----+

root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- blue: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- purple: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- green: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- yellow: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- orange: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- pink: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- red: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- white: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- black: integer (nullable = true)
```

From then on, the script continues

```
// Creating a list for which columns to draw from the main dataframe
val a = List("green", "blue")

// Creating the mini dataframe to perform the function upon
val test_df = df.select(a.map(col): _*)

// The new dataframe will now go through the 'Test' function defined above
val df_function = test_df.rdd.map(col => Test(col(0).toString.toDouble, col(1).toString.toDouble))

// Converting the RDD output back to a dataframe (of one column)
val df_convert = df_function.toDF
```

As a reference, the output looks as follows

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|500.0|
|562.0|
|746.0|
+-----+
```

The last line of the script is to add it to the main dataframe as follows

```
 df = df.withColumn("new column", df_convert)
```

But as stated above, I receive the following error:

```
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

   (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

**//////////EDIT////////////**

@user9819212 solution works for simplistic methods but when calling one a bit more complex, I get the following error

```
    test2_udf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function5>,DoubleType,Some(List(DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType, DoubleType)))
    java.lang.ClassCastException: $anonfun$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function1
```

So I tried to create another simplistic version of my code with a few extra changes to the test function that is called

```
// test function - will be used as part of the main script below
def Test (valueone: Double, valuetwo: Integer): Double = {
    val test = if(valuetwo > 2000) valueone + 4000 else valueone
    val fakeList = List(3000,4000,500000000)
    val index = fakeList.indexWhere(x => x>=valueone)
    val test2 = fakeList(index - 1) * valueone
    test2
}

val test_udf = udf(Test _)

df = df.withColumn(
   "new column", 
   test_udf(col("green").cast("double"), col("blue").cast("integer"))
)
```

At first that seems to work but when I try to view the dataframe with the command

```
df.show
```

I get the following error

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 153.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 153.0 (TID 192, localhost, executor driver): 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (double, int) => double)
```

Comment: @Andrey Tyukin I've changed the title, is it more appropriate now or should it not reference the Dataset[Row] type?

Comment: The title is fine, thank you for updating it.

Comment: Looking at your edited Test function, there is only one mistake i.e. when the index is 0 (when `fakeList.indexWhere(x => x>=valueone)`) returns 0. You have to handle that. Otherwise the udf function looks perfect. But you can refactor the code using when inbuilt function

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan ah I may have simplified it too much again, my bad - I'm really just stuck with the following error ==>  test2_udf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function5>,DoubleType,Some(List(DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType, DoubleType)))
    java.lang.ClassCastException: $anonfun$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function1 - when I put it to my main script, I can provide more details if needed

Comment: comments are not good for codes. can you update the question the the error and `test2_udf` function definition and how you are invoking it?

Comment: meanwhile you can check my detailed answer below :)

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan upon first glance I believe you may be right, I'm without my normal computer at the moment so I cannot access my code but I will review my code with what you've mentioned in your comment when I get my computer back and I'll accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add columns from another `DataFrame` (or `DataFrame`) this way. Just use `UserDefinedFunction`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf._

val test_udf = udf(Test _)

df.withColumn(
   "new column", 
   test_udf(col("green").cast("double"), col("blue").cast("double"))
)
```

or with such simple function:

```
df.withColumn(
   "new column", 
   2 * col("green").cast("double") + col("blue").cast("double")
)
```

Comment: @user9819212 you're solution works for the simplistic function I've provided but when I try to implement it to my real script, I get errors (this is my fault because I tried to simplify the script too much so it would be easier to post on StackExchange)

I'll edit my original post to explain what I mean in a minute

Answer (score 0):

If you go the [api document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#withColumn(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) it is clearly mentioned as

> > `public DataFrame withColumn(java.lang.String colName, Column col)
> >     Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.`

As you can see that second argument should be a `Column` and you have been passing a `DataFrame`.

**thats the cause of the issue.**

And you are trying to add a column from `df_convert` to `df`. The two dataframes are totally different. For that case you will have to look at either [join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#join(org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)) if you want to separate the dataframes

Or at [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) to be used with withColumn api as Column.

## Updated

Looking at your first log

> > `test2_udf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function5>,DoubleType,Some(List(DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType, DoubleType)))`

suggests that you have your `udf` function defined as

```
def Test(valueone: Double, valuetwo: Integer, valuethree: String, valuefour: Double, valuefive: Double): Double = {
  ???
  //calculation parts
}
val test2_udf = udf(Test _)
//Test: Test[](val valueone: Double,val valuetwo: Integer,val valuethree: String,val valuefour: Double,val valuefive: Double) => Double
//test2_udf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function5>,DoubleType,Some(List(DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType, DoubleType, DoubleType)))
```

and your second log

> > `java.lang.ClassCastException: $anonfun$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function1`

suggests that you are passing only one argument in the `test2_udf` call as

```
df.withColumn("new column", test2_udf(col("green").cast("double"))).show(false)
//java.lang.ClassCastException: A$A30$A$A30$$anonfun$test2_udf$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function1
```

If you focus on `cannot be cast to scala.Function1` part of the error message, *it clearly suggests the number of columns passed to the udf functions*

If you **pass three arguments then you get** following

```
df.withColumn("new column", test2_udf(col("green").cast("double"),col("green").cast("double"),col("green").cast("double"))).show(false)
//java.lang.ClassCastException: A$A31$A$A31$$anonfun$test2_udf$1 cannot be cast to scala.Function3
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier, but your updated part is the right answer to the second part of my question (i.e. when I started encountering errors) - so thanks :)

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. you can always upvote when you would be eligible ;)